# Trying to remove spaces in a value from sql table

Tags: c#, sql

I'm loading data from a table into a textbox and I'm getting spaces.  I tried putting rtrim in the select statement but when I do that I get an error saying "column does not belong to table."  I also tried doing textbox.text.trim() and that does not remove the spaces either.  Any help would be appreciated.

```
SqlCommand sqlcom = new SqlCommand("SELECT rtrim(firstname), lastname, address, addresstwo, city, state, zip, phone, email FROM CustomerTbl WHERE customerrid =" + intCustomerid, AppClass.thisConnect);

SqlDataReader sqldataR = sqlcom.ExecuteReader();
DataTable dt = new DataTable("customer");

dt.Load(sqldataR);

AppClass.thisConnect.Close();

txtFirstname.Text = dt.Rows[0]["firstname"].ToString();
```

Comment: `txtFirstname.Text = dt.Rows[0]["firstname"].ToString().Trim();`? And if you want to use it in the SQL statement you might want to use it like `SELECT rtrim(firstname) AS FName, lastname ...` and then `dt.Rows[0]["FName"].ToString()`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Add an `AS` clause to your `SELECT` statement.

```
SELECT rtrim(firstname) AS trimmedFirstName
```

for instance. Then make sure to use that column name in your code.

```
txtFirstname.Text = dt.Rows[0]["trimmedFirstName"].ToString();
```