# how to set combobox text to bet trimmed while retrieving from database in c#

Tags: c#, sql, combobox

I'm working with winforms in c#.net.

I have a combobox using data binding items.

While creating my database I have used `[nvarchar](50)` as datatype for my column.

Here I'm getting into a problem, the combobox is getting the data with 50 chars even there are only 5 chars. That means here the combobox is retrieving the data with nulls or empty or spaces up to 50 chars..

Finally after selecting any item the combobox color is changing so that the Item which I selected is not visible.

What to do to remove these problems?

As follows my retrieve code

```
try
        {
            ConnectionStringSettings consettings = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["attendancemanagement"];
            string connectionString = consettings.ConnectionString;
            SqlConnection cn = new SqlConnection(connectionString); 
            cn.Open();
            SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("select employee_id,employee_name from Employee_Details", cn);
            SqlDataReader dtr;
            dtr = cmd.ExecuteReader();
            DataTable dt = new DataTable();
            dt.Columns.Add("employee_id", typeof(string));
            dt.Columns.Add("employee_name", typeof(string));
            dt.Load(dtr);
            comboBox1.DisplayMember = "employee_id";
            comboBox1.DisplayMember = "employee_name";
            comboBox1.DataSource = dt;
            cn.Close();
            autoinc();


        }
```

and for insert

```
try
        {
            ConnectionStringSettings Consettings = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["attendancemanagement"];
            string connectionString = Consettings.ConnectionString;
            SqlConnection cn = new SqlConnection(connectionString);
            cn.Open();
            byte[] imageBt = null;
            FileStream fstream = new FileStream(this.txtimagepath.Text, FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Read);
            BinaryReader br = new BinaryReader(fstream);
            imageBt = br.ReadBytes((int)fstream.Length);
            //ms.Position = 0;


                SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(@"INSERT INTO Employee_Details
                      (s_no,employee_id, employee_name, designation, date_of_birth,age, date_of_join, salary, pre_exeprience, gender, image_of_employee, image_path,email_id,mobile_no)
 VALUES        ('" + txtsno.Text.Trim() + "','" + txtemployeeid.Text.Trim() + "','" + txtemployeename.Text.Trim() + "','" + Convert.ToString(comboBox1.SelectedItem).Trim() + "','" + dtpdob.Value.ToString("dd/MM/yyyy").Trim() + "','" + txtage.Text.Trim() + "','" + dtpdoj.Value.ToString("dd/MM/yyyy").Trim() + "'," + txtsalry.Text.Trim() + ",'" + Convert.ToString(comboBox2.SelectedItem).Trim() + "','" + gender.Trim() + "',@IMG,'" + txtimagepath.Text.Trim() + "','"+txtemailid.Text+"','"+txtmobileno.Text+"')", cn);

               // cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();

                SqlDataReader sqReader;

                cmd.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("@IMG", imageBt));
                sqReader = cmd.ExecuteReader();
                cn.Close();
                MessageBox.Show("saved successfully");
                ResetFields();
           // }

            //ResetFields();
            autoinc();
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            MessageBox.Show(ex.Message);
        }
```

Comment: Share your code for retrieving and binding.

Comment: here i shared my code @prem

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If haven't, you could trim every retrieved string before populating the combobox. But maybe I misunderstand the problem.

```
dt.Load(dtr);
foreach (DataRow row in dt.Rows)
{
    var name = (string)row["employee_name"];
    row["employee_name"] = name.Trim();
}
comboBox1.DisplayMember = "employee_id";
comboBox1.DisplayMember = "employee_name";
comboBox1.DataSource = dt;
```

You probably have some issue when loading the data, but this should solve the length issue for now

Comment: where should i insert this code and what is option @Lejdholt

Comment: I missed that you updated your question with example code. I will look at it and see if my answer is possible.

Comment: Incase if I use combobox items in that data bound items to combobox control..how to solve it @Lejdholt

Comment: I do not understand the question.

Answer (score 2):

This [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15977351/trying-to-remove-spaces-in-a-value-from-sql-table) seems similar to your's, You can modify your code using the solution given here.
In case the link is not working here's the code from that post.

Add an AS clause to your SELECT statement.

```
SELECT rtrim(firstname) AS trimmedFirstName
```

for instance. Then make sure to use that column name in your code.

```
txtFirstname.Text = dt.Rows[0]["trimmedFirstName"].ToString();
```

Answer (score 0):

Nvarchar should not have padded spaces.

pls check this out and see what you may have missed.

http://thecsharpcoding.blogspot.sg/2013/05/c-combobox-using-datatable.html

```
//include this
using System.Data.OleDb;

//declare
OleDbConnection OCON = null;
OleDbDataReader ODR = null;
//create connection
OCON = new OleDbConnection(@"Provider=SQLOLEDB;Data Source=192.168.0.1;Initial Catalog=TESTDATABASE;User ID=TESTUSER;Password=TESTPASS;");

try{
    //open connection
    OCON.Open();           

    //create command   
    OleDbCommand OCMD = null;       
    OCMD.CommandText = "SELECT ID, DESCRIPTION FROM TABLE";
    //execute command
    ODR = OCMD.ExecuteReader();

    //load datareader to datatable      
    DataTable DT = new DataTable();
    DT.Load(ODR);

    //attach datatable to combobox
    comboBox1.DisplayMember = "DESCRIPTION";
    comboBox1.ValueMember = "ID";
    comboBox1.DataSource = DT;

    //close connection
    OCON.Close();
}catch(OleDbException ex){
    MessageBox.Show(ex.ToString());
}
```